# how can i replace content of text area by PHP script in below mentioned code

Tags: php

I have taken 2 text boxes and 1 text area
User will be to search the content through search box
and provides by which word it should be replaced.

Scenerio 1 :

I want to replace "Good" with word "bad"
But this code does not replace the text area content.
It rather appends with the new replaced string

what's the solution ??

```
<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

<p>
<label for="search">Search :</label>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="replace">Replace</label>
<input type="text" name="replace" id="replace" />
</p>

<p><Br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
<label for="textarea"></label>
</p>

<p><br />
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"  >
"Good morning how are you today are you feeling Good.";
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
     $search = $_POST["search"];
 $replace = $_POST["replace"];
 $textarea = $_POST["textarea"];

 $newtext = str_replace($search,$replace,$textarea);
     echo $newtext;

}

?>
   </textarea>
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show an example of how this goes wrong (with real data)

Comment: How are you actually pushing the text into the textarea?

Comment: this should work fine. Maybe show more code

Comment: @shanethehat I have added the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the conditional statement in PHP to control whether the default text is shown.  At the moment you are just adding the dynamic text after it.

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"  >
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $search = $_POST["search"];
            $replace = $_POST["replace"];
            $textarea = $_POST["textarea"];

            $newtext = str_replace($search,$replace,$textarea);
            echo $newtext;
        } else {
            echo "Good morning how are you today are you feeling Good.";
        }
    ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Script

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="srch.php" method="post">
Find: <input type="text" name="find" value=><br><br>
Replace: <input type="text" name="replace" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Replace"/><br><br>

<textarea name="maintext" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php script.......

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$find= $_POST['find'];
$replace= $_POST['replace'];
$text= $_POST['maintext'];
if (isset($find) && isset($replace))
{
$newtext= str_replace($find, $replace, $text);
}
?> 
<form action="" method="post">
Find: <input type="text" name="find" value='<?php echo $find; ?>'/><br><br>
Replace: <input type="text" name="replace" value='<?php echo $replace; ?>'/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Replace"/><br><br>

<textarea name="maintext" rows="8" cols="80"><?php echo $newtext; ?></textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```